# Como cadastrar o valor de um input="text" no banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Como posso incluir o valor do input de nome `identificador` para ser salvo no banco de dados, com o código abaixo:

```
<?php
require_once "conexao.class.php";
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=informacoes;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$msg = false;
if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
$extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'],-4));
$novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao;


$diretorio = "upload/";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

$query = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO arquivo (codigo, arquivo, identificador) VALUES (null, '$novo_nome' );");

$query->execute();

if ($query->execute()) $msg = "Imagem enviada com sucesso!!!";
else $msg = "Falha ao enviar a imagem.";

}

?>

<body bgcolor="#008080">
    
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<div style='background:white;'><center><h1><font face="CALIBRI">------UPLOAD DE IMAGEM ------</font></h1></center>

</br>   


<center><?php if ($msg != false) echo "<p> $msg </p>"; ?></center>
<center>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Identificador: <input type="text" name="identificador" size="3" >


    Arquivo: <input type="file" required name="arquivo">

    <input type="submit" value="Salvar">

</br>
</br>
<h1><center><font face="CALIBRI">-----------------------------------------</font></center></h1> 
</form>
</center></div>
</a>
</body>
```

Estou com dificuldade nessa parte.

Answer (score 1):

Esse campo `código` é a chave primária da tabela `arquivo`? Se for pode fazer algo assim:

```
    $identificador = $_POST['identificador'];
    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

    $query = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO arquivo (arquivo, identificador) 
    VALUES ( ?, ? )");

    $query->bindParam(1, $arquivo);
    $query->bindParam(2, $identificador);

    if ($query->execute()) 
        $msg = "Imagem enviada com sucesso!!!";
    else 
        $msg = "Falha ao enviar a imagem.";
```

Comment: Sim, é a pk. E a sua solução foi perfeita, funcionou devidamente. Obg

Comment: Que bom, aproveite para dar uma pesquisar nesse "bindParam" é interessante sempre passar por ele quando vai fazer uma inserção no banco de dados para evitar sql injection.